# Dell Precision T3500 - single SATA disk as RAID

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata, dell-precision, fakeraid

Hopefully a quick question - my workstation has been configured with a single SATA hard disk, but the BIOS has the SATA controller configured as RAID, so essentially the disk is being exposed to Windows through a fakeRAID controller. Would this adversely affect performance versus AHCI? I'm noticing significant slow-downs with heavy disk IO and wondering if this is the cause. Obviously due to Windows architecture, changing the setting to AHCI stops Windows booting. Just want to know if it's worth raising the issue with the IT guys.